# PyQt Mouse Position Locally and Globally

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

I have 2 GroupBoxes and I would like to get the current mouse position local to each GroupBox and globally .

That's What I want to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 1):

check https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcursor.html#pos

> QPoint QCursor::pos()
>   Returns the position of the cursor (hot spot) of the primary screen in global screen coordinates.
>
> You can call QWidget::mapFromGlobal() to translate it to widget coordinates.